# R Shiny App Crashes on Launch Windows 10

Tags: r, shiny

Whenever I run **any** Shiny app in Google Chrome with `launch.browser = TRUE`, if there are already no tabs open in Chrome, the app will come up dead (see screenshot below). However, if I have a tab open already, the app loads and runs fine. This is not an issue with Internet Explorer, only with Chrome. However I need to use Chrome for my app because it supports editing a D3 table object, whereas IE does not.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/garrettgman/6673251) is a simple Shiny app in case you would like to test something out with it, but again this happens with every Shiny app I try to run in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: could you share the console output (Chrome: F12 - Console)

Comment: Interestingly enough I cannot access the console. Neither `F12` nor right-clicking on the page works. In addition to that I just noticed that if I'm at that gray screen and I try to load a different webpage, I am stuck at the same screen.

Comment: :O ok, sry then im afraid i cant help.

Comment: Can you try Left-click on the page and select `inspect` on the pop-up menu?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Nothing responds, it's the strangest thing. I can't get to `inspect`.